# Form submit without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Can someone show me a tutorial of using **jquery to display successful form submission** **without refreshing the page**. Something like that happens on gmail when a message is delivered and the yellow overlay that shows that you message was delivered and then fade outs.
**I want the message to be displayed depending on the result of the form submission.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok ... something like this ... but I didn't try it ... so use it just like tutorial.. You can also use json

js:

```
function processForm() { 
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: form_process.php,
            data: 'user_name=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('user_name').value),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#message').html(data);
            }
        } );
}
```

html:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="processForm();return false;">
<input type='text' name='user_name' id='user_name' value='' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
<div id='message'></div>
```

form_process.php

```
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
if(do something){
     echo "login success";
else{
     echo "login unsuccessful";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of jatt is almost right. But don't forget to set the url attribute into ''
This might saves you some minutes of debugging hopefully