# Refreshing a single div element in a page with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm asynchronously posting a form, and I want to refresh a div element upon completion of the form post. I have everything coded already, I just don't know how to (and if it is even possible) to refresh a single div in this manner. Any help?

Comment: you can let your ajaxresponse be that same div(with updated elements of course) and then just replace the old one with the response

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form submit without page refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776900/form-submit-without-page-refresh)

Answer (score 2):

if the div has an id of "foo", and the name of your data is 'data'

```
$(#"foo").html(data);
```

this would be in the callback of your post or ajax call

```
$.post(myURL, function (data) {
   $(#"foo").html(data);
```

}

Comment: @Sennheiser - does this answer the question??

Answer (score 1):

If you have the HTML, then it's as simple as:

```
$('#yourDiv').html(responseFromYourAjaxCall);
```

If you're asking how to get the response from your ajax call, it's like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my/url',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data)
    {
       // This Callback is executed when the post is successful.
       // 'data' is the response from the server. 
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in my [AJAXFetch](http://phrogz.net/JS/AJAXFetch/) jQuery plug-in, which lets you use markup to perform AJAX posts and refresh elements (like your div) on the page with the result.

Comment: I wonder why the down vote. The library was specifically written to deal with the use case of submitting information via AJAX and swapping out elements on the page with the result, as the OP is asking for.