# Is there a way to have a simple refresh of an element?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to refresh an element in my page upon a click of a button. Basically, I just need a div to just pull the same HTML it pulled when I first came to the page. Nothing with Ajax callbacks.

How can I do this?

```
$('#button').live('click',function() {
    //refresh #div  
});
```

Comment: So if I, say, had an `<input type="button">` element, what you're saying is that when it's clicked, it just reloads itself? Is this because you've made changes to it via. jQuery or some other means since the page was loaded? Please provide a little more detail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refreshing a single div element in a page with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489602/refreshing-a-single-div-element-in-a-page-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

well on load you can do:

```
$('div').each(function(){
   $(this).data('orig_html',this.innerHTML);
})
```

and then in ur refresh:

```
$('#button').live('click',function() {
    $('div').each(function(){
       $(this).html($(this).data('orig_html'));
    }) 
});
```

here is the [manual on jQuery data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

fiddle showing you is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/wSqnM/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click( function(){
     $("#yourDiv").load("page_url");
});
```

> Check out the documentation http://api.jquery.com/load/ about the load function.
>  
>   I think this is simpler and what you might be looking for.
>   Hope that helps