# how do you reload a form using ajax/jquery without refresh page?

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax

I am submitting a form using ajax and rails to rate an article using stars but the form doesn't reload after submission so the action is still mapping to create rather than update if I try to change the star rating after submitting? only after I refresh the page does the star rating change. How do I reload a form in the page using ajax without refreshing the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form submit without page refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776900/form-submit-without-page-refresh)

Comment: please give some code